# Permit array of strong params without using nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

I have an array of users I want to save in my database. An example when shown in the console after a `POST` is made:

> "users"=>[{"name"=>"Job", "email"=>"*****"}, {"name"=>"Ed", "email"=>"****"}]

No nested attributes going on here. How to format strong params for this?

```rb
def user_params
  params.fetch(:user, {}).permit(:name, :email, ...)
end
```

This may work for saving a single user but I'm passing an array of users. I'm currently storing the user in a "dirty" manner:

```rb
users = params[:users]

users.each do |user|
  User.create(name: user[:name], email: user[:email])
end
```

I'd like to refactor and do something like:

```rb
User.create(user_params)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To permit a param key containing an array of hashes you pass the name as the key and an array of permitted attributes:

```
def user_params
  params.permit(users: [:name, :email, ...])
        .fetch(:users, [])
end
```

The output will be an array of `ActionController::Parameters` instances or an empty array if the key is not present:

```
[#<ActionController::Parameters {"name"=>"Job", "email"=>"*****"} permitted: true>,
 #<ActionController::Parameters {"name"=>"Ed", "email"=>"****"} permitted: true>]
```

Comment: May be another method name is better to use. So that it continues to work for a single user

Comment: @mechnicov agreed. I just went with the naming in the question.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried everything except by adding `.fetch(:users, [])`. Many thanks.

Comment: I think one of the things that people get confused by is that in Rails your params are almost always nested in a hash and when you're using `permit/fetch` to get to the second level. What helped me to really understand it was the realization that you can do `params = ActionController::Parameters.new(foo: 'bar')` and just play around with strong parameters in the console.